# test class is not running execute method

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

thsi is batch class:

```
global class Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Integer currentYear = System.Today().year();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        string query = 'select Id,Distributor_AID__c,Distributor_AID__r.Email,Distributor_AID__r.Name,Group_code__c,Customer_Code__c,Year__c  from Value_Edge__c Where Group_code__c != null and Year__c =: currentYear';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Value_Edge__c> scope){
        Date dtToday = system.today();
        integer nMonth = dtToday.month();
        integer nBatchRunDay = dtToday.day();
        ValueEdge__mdt objNotifyDates = [Select Id, Notification_Day__c,Notification_Remainder_Day__c from ValueEdge__mdt];
        
        Boolean STartQuarterInitial = false;
        if(nBatchRunDay == objNotifyDates.Notification_Day__c && (nMonth == 1 || nMonth == 4 || nMonth == 7 || nMonth == 10)){
            STartQuarterInitial = true;
        }
        
        Boolean EndQuarterReminder = false;
        if(nBatchRunDay == objNotifyDates.Notification_Remainder_Day__c && (nMonth == 1 || nMonth == 4 || nMonth == 7 || nMonth == 10)){
            EndQuarterReminder = true;
        }
        if(scope != null && scope.size() > 0 ){
            List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            List <string> lstEmail = new List <string>();
            system.debug('scope' + scope);
            
            if(STartQuarterInitial == true || EndQuarterReminder == true){
                for(Value_Edge__c objVE : scope){
                    if(objVE.Distributor_AID__c != null){
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                        
                        if(objVE.Distributor_AID__r.Email != null){
                            lstEmail.add(objVE.Distributor_AID__r.Email); 
                        }
                        system.debug('lstEmail'+ lstEmail.size());
                        if(lstEmail != null && lstEmail.size() > 0){
                            mail.setToAddresses(lstEmail);
                            if(STartQuarterInitial == true){
                                mail.setSubject('Value Edge window open for submission');
                                String messageBody = 'Hi ' +  objVE.Distributor_AID__r.Name + ',' + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'The Value Edge window is open for the quarter till 15th of the month.'+
                                    ' Request you to fill the details and Save/Submit your Value Edge request' + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Below are the details: ' + '<br/>' ;
                                messageBody += 'Group Code: : ' + objVE.Group_Code__c + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Customer Code : ' + objVE.Customer_Code__c + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Year : ' + integer.valueOf(objVE.Year__c) + '<br/>' ;
                                messageBody += 'Kindly take approriate action.' + '<br/>';
                                mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
                                mailList.add(mail);
                            }else if(EndQuarterReminder == true){
                                mail.setSubject('Gental Reminder for Value Edge');
                                String messageBody = 'Hi ' +  objVE.Distributor_AID__r.Name + ',' + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'The Value Edge window is open for the quarter till 15th of the month.'+
                                    ' Request you to fill the details and Save/Submit your Value Edge request' + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Below are the details: ' + '<br/>' ;
                                messageBody += 'Group Code: : ' + objVE.Group_Code__c + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Customer Code : ' + objVE.Customer_Code__c + '<br/>';
                                messageBody += 'Year : ' + integer.valueOf(objVE.Year__c) + '<br/>' ;
                                messageBody += 'If already submitted please ignore the same!' + '<br/>';
                                mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
                                mailList.add(mail);
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                    lstEmail.clear();
                }
                Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);  
            } 
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
```

and this is my test class:

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class Test_Batch_ValueEdge {
    static testMethod void Testdatavalueedge() 
    {
    
        List<Account> lstAccount = new list<Account>();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='Orienfdft Enterprise (G) Pvt. Ltd';
        acc.Group_code__c = 'GRP123';
        acc.ERPCode__c =5458;
        acc.Name ='TestdfdDemo';
        acc.Customer_ID__c= '234';
        acc.GST_Number__c='abcdefgh123456GG';
        acc.Credit_limit__c= 3400;
        acc.TAN_number__c='12356';
        acc.ERPCode__c = 3000;
        acc.TM_code__c= 7800;
        acc.Email_Id__c = 'Test@gmail.com';
        acc.PAN_number__c='9098745466';
        acc.TM_Name__c='Demo';
        acc.Distributor_Owner__c = userInfo.getUserId();
        lstAccount.add(acc);
        insert lstAccount;
        
        Integer currentYear1 = System.Today().year();
        List<Value_Edge__c> lstvalue = new List<Value_Edge__c>();
        Value_Edge__c objVE = new Value_Edge__c();
        objVE.Distributor__c = acc.Id;
        objVE.Group_Code__c = acc.Group_code__c;
        objVE.Customer_Code__c = string.valueOf(acc.ERPCode__c);
        objVE.Year__c = 2021;
        objVE.Distributor_AID__c = userInfo.getUserId();
        lstvalue.add(objVE);
        insert  lstvalue;
        
        
        
        string currentYear = string.valueOf(System.today().year());
        List<Program_criteria__c> lstPC =  new List<Program_criteria__c>();        
        Program_criteria__c objc = new Program_criteria__c();
        objc.calculation_Basis__c = 'Percentage';
        objc.Core_Area__c = 'Reach';
        objc.Group_Outlet__c = 'Group';
        objc.Is_prorated__c = true;
        objc.Value_compared__c = 10;
        objc.Key_criteria__c = 'Additional 10% Net new end customer on total secondary sales end customer base as on 31st Dec 2020.For >10%, a prorated multiplier will be applied';
        objc.Parameters__c = 'Net New Customer addition';
        objc.Is_Active__c = true;
        objc.Year__c = string.valueOf(system.today().year());
        objc.Year__c = currentYear;
        objc.Is_Group_Total_Row__c = true;
        lstPC.add(objc);
        insert lstPC;
        
        
        List<VE_Calculation__c> lstve = new List<VE_Calculation__c>();
        VE_Calculation__c VEcal = new VE_Calculation__c();
        VEcal.calculation_Basis__c = '';
        VEcal.Value_Edge__c = objVE.Id;
        VEcal.Group_Code__c = objVE.Group_Code__c;
        VEcal.Year__c = objc.Year__c;
        VEcal.Value_Edge__c =objVE.Id;
        VEcal.Unique_Id__c = objc.Id + objVE.Group_Code__c + system.today();
        VEcal.Key_criteria__c = objc.Key_criteria__c;
        VEcal.Parameter__c = objc.Parameters__c;
        VEcal.Core_Area__c = objc.Core_Area__c;
        VEcal.Status__c = 'Verified';
        lstve.add(VEcal);
        upsert lstve ;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Batch_ValueEdge batchvalueedge = new Batch_ValueEdge();
        Database.executeBatch(batchvalueedge);
        batchvalueedge.execute(null, lstAccount);
        
        Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID cb = New Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID();

        Database.QueryLocator ql = cb.start(null);
        cb.execute(null,lstvalue);  
        cb.Finish(null);
        
        Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID valueedgebatch = new Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID();
      //  Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID.fakeMethod();
        Database.executeBatch(valueedgebatch);
        Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID(), 200);
        //Batch_ValueEdge_NotifyAID.Fakemethod();
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SSE ! While creating Value_Edge__c record you are giving Year__c as 2021. But your start query has current year filter. Can you check and update based on it

Comment: tried with 2022, but even if its covering select query, its not covering the for loop.

Comment: Is the test class covering Execute method till for loop?

Comment: yes let it be, solved

Comment: Hi Kapil, If the issue is resolved then can you put how it got resolved so it helps other developers if they face the same issues

Comment: it all depends on the Custom metadata settings